# Scroll to a dynamic element in a scroll suggestions

Tags: html, css, svelte

I'm building a city suggestions and as I've added scroll by arrows functionality, I have noticed that the logic works correctly, but as I've scroll more than the visible viewport (max-height), than the other suggestions which we can call "active" are not visible, we need to manually scroll to them, is it possible to somehow scroll together to see them?

I need to find a way to manually force the viewport to be on the active suggestion top, but how can I achieve it?

[image]

Things in action:
https://i.gyazo.com/80c85e1112a4562e8fc57e268916abac.mp4

Styles for wrapper: `flex-col, max-height: 320px, overflow-y: auto`

Logic block:

```
<div class:invisible={ ! is_suggestions_visible } class:opacity-0={ ! is_suggestions_visible } class="flex flex-col absolute z-10 mt-3 w-full bg-purewhite rounded-b-xl max-h-[320px] overflow-y-auto" style="box-shadow: 8px 8px 40px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;">
{#each visible_suggestions as suggestion, i}
<div
    class:bg-white={active_suggestion_i == i}
    on:click={() =>
    toggle_active_suggestion(suggestion.name, suggestion.pk, suggestion.is_munipacity || false)}
    class:rounded-b-xl={i + 1 == visible_suggestions.length}
    class="py-2 px-4 transition ease-in-out cursor-pointer hover:bg-white"
    >
    <p class="text-primary font-medium">{suggestion.name}</p>
    <p class="text-secondary"><span class="font-medium">{suggestion.count}</span> active listings</p>
</div>
{/each}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) for that, e.g.

```js
function scrollOnActive(node, active) {
    function update(active) {
        if (active)
            node.scrollIntoView({ block: 'nearest' });
    }
    update(active);

    return { update };
}
```

```html
<div
    class:bg-white={active_suggestion_i == i}
    use:scrollOnActive={active_suggestion_i == i}
    ...>
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/cc69616a59b64bf1a1ab5e7fb03be5b4?version=3.55.1)

The function [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) has various options to additionally adjust scroll behavior. You could also perform additional checks if you do not want to always trigger a scroll.

Comment: Strange behaviour https://gyazo.com/5c8a19dc9e8575c4d6aec3b9dc99887f

Comment: Use `block: 'nearest'` as `scrollIntoView` option to prevent the page from scrolling as well.